# Is it possible to change the default geolocation alert message in PhoneGap + iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app created using phonegap. I want to change the default location permission alert message without touching the objective-c codebase. Is this possible in phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

The alert is created by iOS and cannot be changed by an app

Comment: You may be able to change it by jail breaking the device but there is nothing you can do if you want your app in the app store